# Change text color in bubble popup menu ("Paste/Replace")

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup

When I make a long click or tap on the blue cursor inside any EditText field inside my app, a bubble context menu with "Paste/Replace" commands appears above the selection. It's text color is white and is very hard to read since it's not contrast with a background color of this menu. The app's theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and every other text inside the app is black.

Here's how it looks.

[image: Here's how it looks].

How can I change that text color? Tried different themes like `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`, it doesn't make any difference.